# Correctly handle HttpStatusCode=Unauthorized with ADAL token

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, xamarin.forms

I am using `ADAL` tokens to call my WebAPI's in a `Xamarin Forms` project. But the `ADAL` tokens expires after 1 hour and the `http` calls throws Unauthorized.

I want to refresh the tokens when Unauthorized status is recieved. I read about and some examples say to use `DelegatingHandler` , but I don't know what `DelegatingHandler` is and  how to use it with the `HTTP client`.

Comment: When you received a token, it's followed by an expiration time, check every time you make a request if the token is about to expire and request a new one using the refresh token

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I checked this issue. For using `DelegatingHandler`, you could refer to the following code snippet:

**CustomMessageHandler:**

```
public class CustomMessageHandler: DelegatingHandler
{
    private string _accessToken;
    private string _refreshToken;
    public CustomMessageHandler(string accessToken, string refreshToken)
    {
        _accessToken = accessToken;
        _refreshToken = refreshToken;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
        var response= await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            /* TODO:
             * 1. Retrieve the new access_token via the refresh_token
             * 2. Update the current field _accessToken
             * 3. Retry the previous failed request    
             */
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new CustomMessageHandler("{your-access-token}", "{your-refresh-token}"));
```